# Getting a list of related models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relationship

Suppose I have an object `Person`, which `has_many` `:foos` and `:bars`.

Given an instance, p (`p = Person.new`), how do I programmatically determine what relationships are available?

i.e. `p.some_method => ["foo", "bar"]`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use Active Record Reflections (API [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html))

In your example:

```
p.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).collect {|a| a.name}
```

Comment: In case anyone wants all associations like I did, just call `reflect_on_all_associations` without a parameter.